# How does Rust compile this example with cyclic trait bounds?

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble understanding how the following example, distilled from [this code](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-is-it-possible-to-clone-a-boxed-trait-object/1714/7), compiles:

```rust
trait A: B {}
trait B {}
impl<T> B for T where T: A {}

struct Foo;
impl A for Foo {}

fn main() {}
```

My current understanding is that

- `trait A: B` declares a trait A with the supertrait B. The [Rust reference on traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#supertraits) states

> Supertraits are traits that are required to be implemented for a type to implement a specific trait.

- `impl<T> B for T where T:A` implements B for any type with the trait A
  .

I expect `impl A for Foo` to fail because before A is implemented for Foo, the blanket implementation can't implement B for Foo, which is required.

My most plausible model for what rustc does while compiling the snippet is as follows:

- implement A for Foo, deferring the check that Foo implements B to a later stage
- implement B for Foo with the blanket implementation, since Foo now implements A
- check that Foo implements B as required by the trait bound `A: B`

Is this in some way close to the truth? Is there any documentation I missed explaining the order in which implementations are processed?

Comment: It's just a guess, I don't know how it actually is. But my guess is that your idea of "it first implements that, then it implements that" is wrong. I'd rather guess that the Rust compiler builds a graph of what implements what, and in that graph, the code you wrote is a loop. The fact that it's circular doesn't negate that it is valid. But again, that's just a guess, I don't actually know. Either way, I'm most curious of what other people here have to say about it. Maybe @ChayimFriedman knows more?

Comment: The Rust compiler definitely doesn't consider things line-by-line or even file-by-file. The compilation unit is the crate, so it has the whole crate full of source code to consider when resolving "does Foo implement B". I also know that it evaluates trait implementations with generics lazily, so it doesn't even think about "does Foo implement B" until some code attempts it. I do wonder if this is properly explained or codified somewhere though, I didn't find anything in a quick search of the reference or rustc guide. This can be inferred though since no documentation is order specific.

Comment: *"no documentation is order specific"* - I take that back, declarative macros are order specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rustc doesn't work "in order". Rather, we first register all impls and then type-check each impl with no particular order. The idea is that we collect a list of *obligations* (of various kinds - one of them is a trait bound), and then we match them against `impl`s (not just; this is only one way to resolve an obligation, but this is what relevant here). Each obligation can create another, recursive obligations and we elaborate them until there are no more.

The way it currently works is that when we check an `impl Trait for Type`, we add an obligation `Type: Trait`. This might seem silly, but we later elaborate it further until all required bounds are met.

So let's say we're currently checking `impl<T> B for T where T: A`. We add one obligation, `T: B`, and match it against `impl B for T`. There is nothing to elaborate further, so we finish successfully.

We then check `impl A for Foo`, and add an obligation `Foo: A`. Since the trait `A` requires `Self: B`, we add another obligation `Foo: B`. Then we start matching obligations: the first obligation, `Foo: A`, is matched by the currently processed `impl` with no additional obligations. The second obligation, `Foo: B`, is matched against `impl<T> B for T where T: A`. This has a new obligate - `T: A` or `Foo: A` - so we try to match that. We successfully match that against `impl A for Foo`, with no additional obligations.

An interesting implication of the above is that if we change the second `impl` to the following:

```rust
impl A for Foo where Foo: B {}
```

Then this no longer compiles with an "overflow evaluating the requirement `Foo: A`" error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0bd6df463d8ad63a95040f4ce950f46)), even though it is essentially the same, because now to prove that `Foo: A` rustc needs to prove that `Foo: B` and again that `Foo: A`, while previously it just registered an obligation for `Foo: B` and not proved it immediately.

**Note:** The above is an over-simplification: for example, there is also a cache, and well-formed obligations, and much more. But the general principle is the same.